# Color cells based on cell value

Tags: vba, excel

Can you help me what is wrong with my code. 
I get an error: Application defined or object defined error.
I would like to color a cell based on a cell value.
If a cell value equal to a cell-1 value the cell should be red.
Error with this line: If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value Then

thank you

```
Sub colorcells()
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Activate
Range("A1").Select
    Dim i As Long
    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 1 To lastrow
        If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(i - 1, 3).Value Then
            Cells(i, 1).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: When `i = 1` you will have an issue with `Cells(i - 1, 3)` since there is no row 0.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using VBA, you can use conditional formatting if you are using Excel 2007 upwards, which is a lot easier to use. It provides you with dialog boxes which allow you to set rules.